# Export NLS_LANG in JDBC

Tags: java, unix, jdbc

Our Oracle database has Russian Characters, 
 We use shell scripting to download file with Russian character data and the file encoding which is downloaded is in Windows-2151, for this, we used

**export NLS_LANG=RUSSIAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251**

We are now downloading the file using Java Database Connectivity (**JDBC**) Oracle Call Interface (OCI) driver in shell scripting and here the NLS_LANG is not being exported and thus the file is in UTF-8 format.

How can we export NLS_LANG setting in JDBC

Comment: Java JDBC does not use `NLS_LANG` setting, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28643) You must set it in your code or java call.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a Statement and execute:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANG=RUSSIAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
```

... just after getting the JDBC Connection.

Another way is to set a proper system locale when starting the JVM:

```
java -Duser.country=... -Duser.language=... -Dfile.encoding=...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Charset RU_ASCII = Charset.forName("GREEK_GREECE.AL32UTF8");

try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("yourfileName.txt"))) {
InputStreamReader a = new InputStreamReader(input, RU_ASCII);
```

You can just use Charset to read the russian files.
`GREEK_GREECE.AL32UTF8` is the charset for `NLS_LANG` then re-export